# Supremum of a Brownian semi-martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, supremum-and-infimum

Consider the process $p_t$ with $t\in[0,1]$
$$
p_t = p_0 +\int_0^t\mu_s\,ds+\int_0^t\nu_s\,dW_s
$$
where $\mu$ and $\nu$ are bounded predictable processes and $W$ is a Brownian motion. Let's assume that $p_t\in(0,1)$ (it is always possible to create such a Brownian semi-martingale considering any continuous and differentiable $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (0,1)$ and a Brownian semi-martingale $X$, then taking $p_t=F(X_t)$, by the Ito-lemma, we have that $p_t$ is still a Brownian semi-martingale). Since the trajectories of $p$ are continuous and $[0,t]$ is a compact set we can say that the maximum of $p_s$ over the interval $[0,t]$, call it $\overline{p}_t$, exists and it is strictly contained in $(0,1)$, that is
$$
\exists\overline{p}_t\doteq \max_{0\leq s\leq t}p_s\in (0,1)
$$
where $\doteq$ means "definition".  My problem is: how much restrictive is to assume  that
$$
\widetilde{p}_t \doteq \sup_{\omega\in\Omega}\overline{p}_t(\omega)\in(0,1)\quad ?
$$
Or, better, am I allowed to put such a restriction?

Comment: Can you explain your notation (the bar over $p$ and the dot over $=$).

Comment: I will modify the text